# Counting from sqlite database cause error

Tags: arrays, android-sqlite

I'm trying to pass an int array from the MainActivity to the databaseadapter to run a count from the sqlite database. I got the code as follow without any errors from eclipse, but once it runs, it crashes.

Code as follows 
for Mainactivity

```
            int one = 1;
            int  five = 5;  

            int[] apple = {one, five};   
            int numr = (int) myDb.getCount(apple);

            TextView textv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wds);
                   textv.setText("There are" + numr + "of entries");
```

For Databaseadapter, Datab,

```
        public int getCount(int[] apple) {
        int fir = apple[1];
        int sec = apple[2];

    int fin = (int) DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, "SELECT COUNT(*)
             FROM TABLE_NAME where  length >= " +fir + "and width >=" 
             + sec, null);  
             return nfin;
```

And the logcat as follows

```
06-10 15:44:05.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1737): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 15:44:05.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1737): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
06-10 15:44:05.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at com.example.pro.Datab.getCount(Datab.java:110)
06-10 15:44:05.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at com.example.pro.MainActivity.onItemSelected(Qus.java:237)
06-10 15:44:05.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:892)
06-10 15:44:05.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:49)
06-10 15:44:05.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:860)
```

As you probably can guess, I'm very new to Android/Java so I would appreciate any help I can get. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart that arrays start from 0, so your indexes should be:

```
int fir = apple[0];
int sec = apple[1];
```

Assuming that your table name is "TABLE_NAME", add a space before `"and width...`, so to read `" and width...`.
Or the query can't be executed

It actually would result in something (not working) like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)FROM TABLE_NAME where  length >= 10and width >=20
```

while it should be something (working) like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME where length >= 10 and width >= 20
```

Comment: Thanks. The additional comment on the white space was prophetic. I made a mistake on it and reread your post to fix it. Appreciate it.

Comment: Wow! "prophetic" sounds great!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Array indexes start from 0, but you've used index 1 and 2 from `apple`.  Index 2 is out of bounds, as noted in the error log:

> java.lang.**ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**: length=2; index=**2** 06-10

Your error has nothing to do with the SQL.

Comment: Sorry about that. Like I said, I'm very new to this. I wasn't sure if it was SQlite or something else from the logcat.